# Trying to work out why my query is sluggish

Tags: c#, sql, performance

So I have this query in C#, it takes about 3.6 seconds to complete.

```
var realReviews2 = from productReview in _productReviewRepository.Table.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.ProductId == productId)
                    join review in _reviewRepository.Table.AsEnumerable() on productReview.Id equals review.ProductReviewId
                    where productReview.IsApproved && review.PictureIds != null && review.PictureIds != ""
                                   select productReview;
                realReviews = realReviews2.ToList();
```

Here is both table designs

Product review table:

[image]

Review Table:

[image]

I did have my where clause like so, but made no difference:

```
var realReviews2 = from productReview in _productReviewRepository.Table.AsEnumerable()
                    join review in _reviewRepository.Table.AsEnumerable() on productReview.Id equals review.ProductReviewId
                    where productReview.ProductId == productId && productReview.IsApproved && review.PictureIds != null && review.PictureIds != ""
                                   select productReview;
```

I'm not sure why it's slow, does anyone have advice to speed it up?
Thanks

> More Info:
> Both tables have 6069 rows

> I have also tried the following, but get this error message
> The specified type member 'ProductReview' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

For this:

```
var realReviews2 = _reviewRepository.Table.Where(x =>
                    x.PictureIds != null && x.PictureIds != "" && x.ProductReview.ProductId == productId).Select(x => x.ProductReviewId).ToList();
                realReviews = _productReviewRepository.Table.Where(x => realReviews2.Contains(x.Id)).Select(x => x)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: we need more info than that sorry. how many rows in the tables? what indexes do you have on them? have you tried running it in SSMS?  (assuming it's ms sql server). if so, please paste the execution plan

Comment: @RodneyEllis both tables have 6069 rows

Comment: also no indexing as far as I'm aware

Comment: `.AsEnumerable()` ? don't do that

Comment: I had to use asenumerable to make it work @TheGeneral

Comment: It looks like with the help of your repository (*sigh*) everything is getting sucked back into memory, then joined, then queried. Ideally you would let these queries be executed on the server where it can use its indexing and query plan. I would suggest by passing the repository completely, and formulate the query without the extra abstraction. Then if its still slow, you would look at profiling the server to see what can be done to make this faster

Comment: @TheGeneral would a stored procedure help here?
Just trying to work out the best option. Thanks

Comment: Yeah sorry I may have fired to soon, are you using Entity framework? Or is your repository wrapping raw sql ? If you are using EF, then this sort of simple query can be done without much effort and executed on the server. Otherwise you are better off to just construct the query in sql by hand. Yes you could use a stored procedure if you are comfortable with that

Comment: @TheGeneral yep entity framework and linq, though I have been having trouble with it.
see the bottom of my question for edit.
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to select all Product reviews of a product where its approved, and only reviews that have a picture id?

Comment: @TheGeneral yep, also matching the product id. I figured it out though, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So so I figured out the query I needed to use in linq, it's fast now at 236ms

```
var realReviews2 = _reviewRepository.Table.Where(x =>
                    x.PictureIds != null && x.PictureIds != "").Select(x => x.ProductReviewId).ToList();
                realReviews = _productReviewRepository.Table.Where(x => realReviews2.Contains(x.Id) && x.ProductId == productId).Select(x => x)
                    .ToList();
```

I was matching the product id in the wrong query